# loop through files and send to web service

Tags: powershell

I need to loop through a directory of files (doc) and send them to a web service, getting back a pdf file (identical name as the doc).

for one file, this works:

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path | Push-Location

$uri = "http://someinternalurl"
$doc= "somefilename.doc"
$pdf= "somefilename.pdf" 

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method POST -InFile $doc-ContentType "application/octet-stream" -OutFile $pdf
```

but with a loop I keep messing up, I'm currently trying:

```
$files = get-childitem c:\in\doc -Filter *.doc
ForEach ($file in $files) {
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path | Push-Location

    $uri = "http://someinternalurl"
    $doc = Get-Content $file.Fullname ## <<-- this is where i'm surely wrong
    $pdf = $file.Basename + '.pdf'

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method POST -InFile $in -ContentType "application/octet-stream" -OutFile $pdf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$DocPath = 'c:\in\doc'
$Uri = 'http://someinternalurl'

Get-ChildItem -Path $DocPath -Filter '*.doc' | ForEach-Object {
    $PdfPath = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + '.pdf')
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method POST -InFile $_.FullName -ContentType 'application/octet-stream' -OutFile $PdfPath
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This goes through without errors & the end result is a pdf with the correct name. Unfortunately it's not correctly processed by the web service, the result is a pdf with a plain text content of the word file, but still much further than i have gotten until now.